# Is it possible to assert that a pointer is pointing to an array?

Tags: c++

I am creating a deconstructor, and I want to assert that my pointer `float *queue` is pointing to an array of floats. The compiler does not seem to like

`assert([]queue);`

and my program seg faults if I use

`assert(queue != NULL);
 delete []queue;`

. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No you cannot. I suggest you ask about your actual problematic code instead, since your question indicates that you have some fundamental design flaw in it.

Comment: you might research typeof and decltype, but that doesn't seem too helpful with just "a pointer"

Comment: Okay, well I am creating a queue from scratch for school. The queue's size is decided at run time, so I thought creating a dynamic array would be the best way to implement the code. I created a constructor that takes an argument for the size of queue, however, they want us to use a constructor with no arguments. Now, I know that MY driver code will always make an array, but I did not want to make an assumption that there will always be a `new float [capacity]` , when calling the deconstructor. @walnut

Comment: @Nate In practice, you should always use `std::vector` for that. If you are not allowed to use it, then `new float[capacity]` is correct. The queue should be a class and the `queue` pointer should be a private member of that class. Only the member functions that you implement should (be able to) change the pointer. This way you can be sure that it is *always* either a null pointer (when you set it to that) or a pointer to a `float` array allocated with `new float[...]`. No outside code should be allowed to change the pointer. Then you don't need the check that you are asking for.

Comment: @walnut ah I see, I thought c++ automatically initialized pointers to null. Your solution makes sense. My pointer was pointing to some random memory (I am assuming, since I declared it, but not initialize it), when the code was running, so then the assert was passing for the `assert( queue != NULL)`. Ill make sure to change it to a nullptr

Comment: @Nate Yes, you need to always initialize all non-class types with a sensible value, preferably immediately when you declare them (btw. since C++11 this works inside classes for class members as well). Only class types can have a default constructor that initializes to a reasonable initial value.

Comment: @walnut thanks for the help. It was very educational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot.

You can test whether a pointer has a null pointer value by comparing it against `nullptr` (or `NULL` in pre-C++11; `NULL` should never be used since C++11), but you can never tell whether a non-null pointer is pointing to a valid object, whether that object is part of an array or whether that object/array was allocated by `new`/`new[]`.

It is the programmer's job to assure that the code can never reach a state where the above information is needed, but unavailable.

The easiest way of doing that is to never use raw `new`/`delete`. Instead only use `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr`.

---

You also don't need to check for a null pointer before calling `delete[]`. `delete[]` can be called with a null pointer, in which case it simply doesn't do anything. You cannot call `delete[]` with a non-null pointer that doesn't have a value returned by `new[]` (and that hasn't been `delete[]`ed yet) tough. That would have *undefined behavior*.